# Need to refer from first register variable to second variable using only the index number

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have two register variables, I loop on the first one and I need to loop on the second using only the index number.

I put this `{{y.results[0].stdout}}` but of course it only stay on the first array.

I want to loop on register y the same as register x index number.

```
- shell: |
         if [[ $(fdisk -l /dev/{{raw_prefix}}{{item}} |  grep '/dev/{{raw_prefix}}{{item}}{{partition}}' | wc -l) = 0 ]]; then fdisk -l /dev/{{raw_prefix}}{{item}} | grep 'Disk /dev' | awk '{print $3}' ; fi 
      ignore_errors: true
      register: x
      with_items: "{{letters}}"

- shell: |
         if [[ $(fdisk -l /dev/{{raw_prefix}}{{item}} |  grep '/dev/{{raw_prefix}}{{item}}{{partition}}' | wc -l) = 0 ]]; then fdisk -l /dev/{{raw_prefix}}{{item}} | grep 'Disk /dev' | awk '{print $4}' ; fi 
      ignore_errors: true
      register: y
      with_items: "{{letters}}"

- shell: echo {{item.stdout}} - {{y.results[????].stdout}}
  with_items: "{{x.results}}"
```

For example:

```
x[0].stdout=10    y[0].stdout=MB
x[1].stdout=5     y[1].stdout=GB
```

So the output should be:

10 - MB
5 - GB

Basically I'm creating a partitioning playbook so that I could determine a raw disk 10GB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in the output change your if statement, use `awk 'OFS=" - "; {print $3, $4}'`. No need to register x and y. One task will provide the required output.

```
- shell: |
         if [[ $(fdisk -l /dev/{{raw_prefix}}{{item}} |  grep '/dev/{{raw_prefix}}{{item}}{{partition}}' | wc -l) = 0 ]]; then fdisk -l /dev/{{raw_prefix}}{{item}} | grep 'Disk /dev' | awk 'OFS=" - "; {print $3, $4}' ; fi 
      ignore_errors: true
      with_items: "{{letters}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that but what I'm trying to do is to loop from sdb up to sdx, u don't know how many disk are there.  So to capture all the 10 (awk $3) you have to fdisk -l (compatible with all version of redhat), so i need also to capture GB (awk $4).  But I figured out that this is hard.  So I can't do it with_items looping, I will do is to hard code it like,

- shell: echo {{x.results[0].item.stdout}} - {{y.results[0].stdout}} >> {{pre_check_logs}}
- shell: echo {{x.results[1].item.stdout}} - {{y.results[1].stdout}} >> {{pre_check_logs}}

By the way this is github,

https://github.com/rv-ansible/disk_mgnt.git